# Undefined offset when assigning a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have two tables - I want to compare their values. If the $xml codes are in the $db, I create the product_db variable, if not - I will display the echo with the relevant information. Unfortunately - I get information undefined offset. I tried with $xml[0] as $product_xml, although it displays the malfunction of the function and only gets the first index of the array - while I need to compare all.

```
$xml = array(
    array(
        "code" => 456,
        "stock" => 33,
        "price" => 249.00,
    ),
    array(
        "code" => 789,
        "stock" => 0,
        "price" => 199.00,
    ),
);

$db = array(
    array(
        "code" => 456,
        "stock" => 432,
        "price" => 251.00,
    ),
    array(
        "code" => 789,
        "stock" => 1,
        "price" => 299.00,
    ),
);

foreach ($xml as $product_xml) {

    if (in_array($product_xml['code'], array_column($db, 'code'))) {

        $product_db = $db[$product_xml['code']];
        $update = false;

    } else {

        echo 'error';
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) here like below:-

```
foreach ($xml as $product_xml) {
   $key = array_search($product_xml['code'],array_column($db,'code')); //check value exist in $db array or not and get the key
    if ($key!==false) {
        $product_db = $db[$key]; //based on key get the value form $db array and assign it to $product_db
        print_r($product_db);// print assigned valued
        $update = false;
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/860464

Note:- In your code `$update` is no where defined.So first defined it before `foreach()` and then use it. Also i am unable to see any significance of this variable in your code(because you used it no-where)

Comment: The update variable is supposed to serve as a flag, based on which I will determine whether the product is suitable for updating or not.

Comment: I test myself - I have 8 minutes for it, then I give you the best answer. It seems to work, but if I had further problems - would you be able to help me?

Comment: For further problems you have to ask new question. You will get answers for-sure

Comment: Okay, although your solution seems to be the most correct. In a few minutes I will mark the answer as the best one.